# Problem with automatic bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have the need to get the bibliography of a latex document in an automatic way. I'm trying since two weeks. Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\graphicspath{immagini}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\big|#1\big|}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage {table}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newenvironment{sistema}
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}
{\end{array}\right.}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=4.5cm,right=2.5cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}

%\usepackage{thebibliography}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
%\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography
%\bibliographystyle{plain} % ad esempio: \bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{biblio.bib} 
%\printbibliography

%
\begin{document}
%********************
\include{frontespizio}
%**************************

\frontmatter
%********************

%***************************
\include{dedica} %DEVI MODIFICARLA
\include{Ringraziamenti}
%********************
\tableofcontents %SOMMARIO
%**************
\mainmatter
%**************
\input{chapter1_introduzione}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
\input{chapter4}
\input{chapter5}
\input{chapter6}
\input{chapter7}
\input{chapter8}
%
%*****************
\backmatter
%****************


\end{document}
```

The bibliography doesn't show in any way. My editor is Worktex. I compile with pdfLaTeX, BibTeX and again pdfLaTeX twice but without any result: the compilation ends well but in the resulting PDF there's no bibliography. I would appreciate any help. Obviously I created the biblio.bib file.

Comment: ehm...this is an English forum, not an Italian one. If you prefer the latter, please visit [the guit forum](http://www.guitex.org).

ehm...questo è un forum inglese, non italiano. Se ne preferisci uno italiano, visita [il forum del guit](http://www.guitex.org)

Comment: @Spike: You could salvage this question if you translated it to English. Then we could reopen it. But only if you want.

Comment: i'm so sorry. i've just sent my main file in tex. i use the texwork editor and i'm in troubles with the automatic latex bibliography. i created my .bib file but i can't visualize the biblio in the pdf. someone could tell me exactly which  commands or packages i'm supposed to use.. AND WHERE TO PUT EM IN THE MAIN FILE. thank u

Comment: @doncherry added the translation. I haven't deleted the italian part, your choice if this is needed. user16357 see my answer. It works (guarda la mia riposta. Il codice proposto funziona)

Answer (score 4):

You misplace the `\printbibliography` command. You have to put it in the position where you need to show the bibliography. The following example work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\graphicspath{immagini}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\big|#1\big|}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage {table}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newenvironment{sistema}
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}
{\end{array}\right.}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=4.5cm,right=2.5cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}




%\usepackage{thebibliography}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

%\bibliographystyle{plain} % ad esempio: \bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{biblio.bib} 
%\printbibliography

%
\begin{document}
%********************
%\include{frontespizio}
%**************************

\frontmatter
%********************

%***************************
%\include{dedica} %DEVI MODIFICARLA
%\include{Ringraziamenti}
%********************
\tableofcontents %SOMMARIO
%**************
\mainmatter
%**************
%\input{chapter1_introduzione}
%\input{chapter2}
%\input{chapter3}
%\input{chapter4}
%\input{chapter5}
%\input{chapter6}
%\input{chapter7}
%\input{chapter8}
%
%*****************
\backmatter
%****************
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I assumed you use the `book` document class because you use the `\frontmatter` (etc..) command. I also switched the position of the `csquotes` and the `biblatex` package, as explained in the documentations.

Comment: I'm not sure if we tolerate question without any sign of English. However: since we tend to improve the codes in questions in other ways than just solving the problem, I would suggest using `cases` or `dcases` instead of user-defined `sistema`. The environment `dcases` needs `mathtools` package.